# Creating PL/SQL Package with procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create an oracle package with some procedures, but I get a compilation error. 
How Can I debug this code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY es IS
    PROCEDURE spisok(parent_id IN INTEGER)
    AS ID SPISOK_UZLOV.SP_ID%TYPE;
        CURSOR child_id IS SELECT fr_id FROM frame WHERE fr_fr_id=parent_id;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO SPISOK_UZLOV VALUES(parent_id);
        OPEN child_id;
        LOOP
            FETCH child_id INTO ID;
            EXIT WHEN child_id%NOTFOUND;
            spisok(ID);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE child_id;
    END spisok;
END es;
```

I get [Err] ORA-24344: success with compilation error.

Comment: calling the same procedure from within the procedure ? isn't this something you should avoid

Comment: Please post the output of `show errors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW ERROR` could give you some hint.

Comment: There is a table SPISOK_UZLOV with one field.

Comment: OK. What does `SHOW ERROR` say the?

Comment: SHOW ERRORS helps me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for the body of the package, did you actually declare the package first? See this link for reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/09_packs.htm

Comment: Yes. package was declared:

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE es IS
PROCEDURE spisok(parent_id IN INTEGER);
end es;

Comment: What do you get when you run the command: show errors procedure es.spisok(<ID>) ?